# How to select values from two different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my SQL Server database. The first is `Test1` and second is `Test2`. There is a column `RegNo` in both tables.

Now I want to select the values from both the tables for a particular `RegNo`.

This is what I'm doing

```
SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
FROM Test1,Test2 JOINS
Test2 ON Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
```

But my query is giving error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
FROM Test1 
INNER JOIN Test2 ON Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
```

Comment: because RegNo is in both tables you also can use `USING` `SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
FROM Test1 
INNER JOIN Test2 USING(RegNo)`

Comment: @Bondye Yes, you could - but you shouldn't: You end up with the same execution plan, but with a SQL snipplet, that doesn't port well. My rule of thumb: If a platform-specific feature brings performance or functionality: Use it. If it just rephrases a portable construct: Do **not** use it.

Answer (score 10):

```
select
    Test1.SurName,
    Test2.Class,
    Test2.Medium
from Test1
inner join Test2
on Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
```

And if you want to select your data for a particular `RegNo`, just add a `WHERE` clause to the end, like so:

```
select
    Test1.SurName,
    Test2.Class,
    Test2.Medium
from Test1
inner join Test2
on Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
where Test1.RegNo = 123456   -- or whatever value/datatype your RegNo is
```

Comment: @Marco :) Thank you!  It looks like it was only a matter of seconds. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
FROM Test1
INNER JOIN Test2
ON Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
```

please see [a visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) this is very helpful in learning joins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
FROM Test1 INNER JOIN Test2
ON Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
WHERE Test1.RegNo = desired_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query with correction.

```
SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
    FROM Test1 INNER JOIN Test2 ON Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo where  Test2.RegNo=Test1.RegNo;
```

**Also you can filter the query by providing the RegNo,on whichEver table u want.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking foe method without join and relation.This will do the trick.

```
select 
   (
   select s.state_name from state s where s.state_id=3
   ) statename,
   (
   select c.description from country c where c.id=5
   ) countryname
   from dual;
```

where dual is a dummy table with single column--anything just require table to view

Answer (score 0):

Very Basic question, try google next time and this now:

```
SELECT Test1.SurName, Test2.Class, Test2.Medium
FROM Test1
inner join Test2 ON Test1.RegNo = Test2.RegNo
```