# How to create a select query with multiple columns querying a single column with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause

I want to get a list of results from my db2 database querying a table having multiple conditions on a same column. Here is an example scenario:

Table1:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5

sample, user, adam, ggg, hdh
sample, source, online, urt, loe
random, user, henr, uuu, kkk
crew, user, mike, nhg, kik
crew, dummy, nothing, irr, wer
ment, maker, hts, ret, opp
```

I am trying to write a select query that will list me the details in the following manner:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
sample, adam, online, ggg
random, henr, , uuu
crew, mike, nothing, irr
ment,  ,  , ret
```

So when col2 has the value **user** I want the corresponding col3 value as one of the column to my select statement. And, when col2 has value in **source or dummy**, I want the corresponding col3 value as another column to my select statement. In this way, I can finally have a list with 4 columns which gets me the unique combination of details that I need.

I have a draft sql query of this kind. I am not sure how to refactor this to get two output columns querying a single column.

```
select col1 , col3 as col2, col3 as col3, col4 from Table1 
where col2='user' or col2 in ('source','dummy')
```

If I do this, I am getting the output in this manner

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
sample, adam, adam, ggg
sample, online, online, ggg
random, henr, henr, uuu
crew, mike, mike, irr
crew, nothing, nothing, irr
```

Comment: Your don't mention `col4` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've mentioned col5 in your input as it's not referred to in your output? It just muddies the water ;-)

Anyway, here's the SQL you need to get the results you're after based on the input/output example:

```
WITH
  USER AS
    ( SELECT COL1
           , COL3 AS COLA
           , COL4 AS COLB
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE COL2 = 'USER'
    )

, SOURCE AS
    ( SELECT COL1
           , COL2 AS COLC
           , COL3 AS COLD
           , COL4 AS COLE
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE COL2 IN ( 'SOURCE'
                      , 'DUMMY'
                      )
    )

SELECT U.COL1
     , U.COLA                       AS COL2
     , COALESCE(S.COLD,'')          AS COL3
     , COALESCE
         ( CASE
             WHEN S.COLC = 'DUMMY'
               THEN S.COLE
               ELSE U.COLB
           END
         , U.COLB
         )                          AS COL4
  FROM USER                  U
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SOURCE     S
    ON S.COL1 = U.COL1
  WITH UR FOR FETCH ONLY;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
select col1,
       max(case when col2 = 'user' then col3 end) as col2,
       max(case when col2 in ('source', 'dummy') then col3 end) as col3,
       max(col4) as col4
from t
group by col1;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Could you tell me why you have specified max in front of the case?

Comment: @SRS . . . It is needed for aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to write `select col1 , col3 as col2, col2 as col3, col4 from Table1...` and then add respective conditions  , as in your case. second and third columns in output are same because you are selecting `col3` in both

Comment: ps , i think  you also need conditioning for `col4`

Comment: What to do if instead of one table there are two and the values mentioned in col2 and col3 in the first box resides in that another table?

Comment: You can use JOIN in that case which enables you to select data from two or more tables , there are different types of joins  so you can use as of your choice and add conditions on them to select rows of your choice . there is a quite similar issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881713/how-to-select-values-from-two-different-tables-in-sql) . Hopefully this help